# Rustのtauriにて実行できない

Tags: windows, rust, build

現在windows11 proにてtauriを使った開発をしたいと思うのですが、実行ができません。

手順としてはmicrosoftビルドツールを入れ、nvm-windowsでnode.jsを入れ、npmにて`npm create tauri-app`を実行し、`npm run tauri dev`を実行しましたがうまくいきません。

事前にルートフォルダ上にdistフォルダを作成しました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このような構成となっております。

tauriにて設定はnpmかつreactで設定してます。

まずは実行してコンパイルが走り、立ち上がるようにしたいので、ご教授お願い致します。

**追記**

以下エラーメッセージです。

```
npm run tauri dev

> try-tauri@0.0.0 tauri 
> tauri dev

'tauri' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、 操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
```

Answer (score 2):

> npm run tauri devを実行しましたがうまくいきません。

質問に書かれている情報を見た限りですと手順には問題はなさそうですが、どのようにうまくいかないですか？　たとえば、エラーメッセージが表示されるのなら、そのメッセージを教えてください。

数ヶ月前にgihyo.jpに記事を書きましたので、そちらも参考にしてみてください。（yarn + Reactを使用）

- [軽量RustフレームワークTauriでデスクトップアプリ開発をはじめよう](https://gihyo.jp/article/2022/10/rust-monthly-topics-02) — gihyo.jp

**追記**

> 以下エラーメッセージです。
>
> ```
> npm run tauri dev
>
> > try-tauri@0.0.0 tauri 
> > tauri dev
>
> 'tauri' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、 操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
> ```

エラーの情報、ありがとうございました。

npmのパッケージが見つからない（ダウンロードされていない）ようです。以下のコマンドを実行してから、再度、`npm run tauri dev`を実行してみてください。

```
npm install
```

これでうまくいくと思います。

私の記事では`yarn`を使っているのでコマンドが微妙に異なりますが、[プロジェクトを作成する](https://gihyo.jp/article/2022/10/rust-monthly-topics-02#gh4XGYZPUu)の「すべてに回答すると、以下のようなメッセージが表示されます。...　指示どおりコマンドを入力してください」のあたりが参考になると思います。

**補足**

私の理解が正しければ、`npm run tauri dev`を実行すると、（`npm install`で入れた）`@tauri-apps/cli`パッケージが起動され、それが（`cargo install tauri-cli`で入れた）`tauri-cli`コマンドを実行する仕組みになっているはずです。（[参考情報](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/tree/dev/tooling/cli/node#this-module)）

`tauri-cli`の方は先ほど入れていただいたので、あとは`npm install`で`@tauri-apps/cli`パッケージを入れれば動くはずです。

Comment: ありがとうございます!読ませていただきました。tauri-cliを入れてなかったので入れてみましたが、うまくいかず・・・
以下エラーメッセージです。
npm run tauri dev

> try-tauri@0.0.0 tauri
> tauri dev

'tauri' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。

Comment: エラーについて承知しました。npm installコマンドで直ると思います。詳しくは回答に追記しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます!npm installで必要なパッケージがインストールされ、うまくいきました。npmについても学習を進めようと思います!

Comment: うまくいって良かったです！